# setTimeOut code not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but it execute only once...

```
$('.' + container).hover(function() {   
        t = setTimeout( function(elem){
            //this should be executed as long as I hover, 
            //with interval declared in viewSpped variable
            $(elem).find('img').first().appendTo('.' + container).fadeOut(500);
            $(elem).find('img').first().fadeIn(800);    

        }(this), viewSpeed);


    }...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: You're executing the function instead of passing it to the setTimeout. Drop the `(this)` after the function statement.

Comment: It's always entertaining to see the different ways a simple function can be twisted and broken, and then "blamed" on something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) only call the callback once, that's normal.

Maybe you want [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) if you want your function to be executed at regular intervals.

And, incidently, there is another error in your code : You probably want

```
t = setInterval( function(elem){
        //this should be executed as long as I hover, 
        //with interval declared in viewSpped variable
        $(elem).find('img').first().appendTo('.' + container).fadeOut(500);
        $(elem).find('img').first().fadeIn(800);    
    }, viewSpeed, this);
```

The arguments passed by `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to the callback are after the duration.

Or, to be more compatible (note that the link I provide also gives the workaround for IE) :

```
var $elem = $(this);
t = setInterval( function(){
         $elem.find('img').first().appendTo('.' + container).fadeOut(500);
         $elem.find('img').first().fadeIn(800);    
}, viewSpeed);
```

Comment: Although it's better to use setTimeout in a loop, so I'd discourage usage of setInterval

Comment: @Nile - That depends, but isn't it a bit incongruous to say "`setInterval` should should be discouraged in a loop"? I mean, what else does `setInterval` do?

Comment: Would you give me some idea about the $ in $elem? This one works perfectly for me, thank you very much for all your answers...

Comment: `$` is just a standard character. I have the habit to prefix by this character the variables holding jQuery wrapped elements. I find it's more clear.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I never said `setInterval` should be discouraged in a loop... I said `setTimeout` should be used in a loop as an alternative.

Comment: *Although it's better to use setTimeout in a loop, so I'd discourage usage of setInterval – Nile 22 hours ago* **?** I know what you were getting at, and I couldn't resist pointing out what I thought funny. But the sentiment you denied making is *exactly* what that statement says. If `setInterval` was not used in a loop-like way, it's kinda like the sixth toe on your dog's foot: A curiosity. There's nothing wrong with `setInterval` (and I use to pedal the same refrain as you). I prefer `setTimeout` but I've learned I don't have to denigrate `setInterval` to prefer `setTimeout` in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` calls its callback with no arguments.  So `elem` will NOT be passed to your callback.  If you were trying to do a self-invoking function, then all you're doing is calling your function immediately, not passing a callback to `setTimeout()`.

I don't know what you expect `elem` to be, but if you want it to be the item that was hovered, you would do that like this:

```
$('.' + container).hover(function() {   
    var self = $(this);
    t = setTimeout( function(){
        //this should be executed as long as I hover, 
        //with interval declared in viewSpped variable
        self.find('img').first().appendTo('.' + container).fadeOut(500);
        self.find('img').first().fadeIn(800);    

    }, viewSpeed);
}...
```

Comment: you can provide to setTimeout the parameters that will be given to the callback : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: @dystroy - yes, but only in some browsers (doesn't work in IE).  Much safer to solve the problem with a variable that you can reference in the callback.

Comment: Just kinda wondering why the `.find('img').first()` it's outside the anonymous function.

Comment: I also tried this code, it executes as long as I hover but appendTo doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Emkey - that's because the rest of your logic is apparently wrong.  We'd have to see your HTML and understand what you're actually trying to accomplish to know how to advise further on that.  This answer fixes the setTimeout problem.

Comment: @minitech - Oops, should have said "why isn't it outside". Kinda repetitive, but apparently everyone's doing it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Oh, because the first image keeps changing. I was originally rewriting it to move it out, but then I saw `appendTo` :P

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function immediately instead of using it as a callback (which wouldn't work anyway, as you need to pass a parameter), and I think you also meant `setInterval`.

```
var elem = $(this);
var container = $('.' + container);

t = setInterval(function() {
        elem.find('img').first().appendTo(container).fadeOut(500);
        elem.find('img').first().fadeIn(800);
    }, viewSpeed);
```

Comment: I fixed it, it executes as long as I hover but appendTo looks like not working...

Comment: @Emkey: If dystroy's answer worked, this one will work. They're functionally equivalent. (But this one's very slightly more efficient.)